# How do I skip the requirement to hit tab twice on a soft link autocomplete?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, terminal.app, autocomplete

When I am in the bash terminal (Mac) and I am selecting a file, I can easily type the first part of a directory and hit tab to have it auto complete, for example:

```
cat ~/Desk [tab] -> cat ~/Desktop/
```

but when I do the same for a symbolic link, it does this:

```
cat ~/cod [tab] -> cat ~/code
```

then I need to hit tab again:

```
cat ~/cod [tab] [tab] -> cat ~/code/
```

is there anyway to get around this?